# Angular2 v3 component router: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I recently switched my angular2 app from the RC router to the v3 router. I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at match`.
```

After enabling tracing on the router to get debug output, it looks like the source of the error is from the router:

```
NavigationError {id: 2, url: "/my/workspace/1252407935628215305/projects", error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at match - common_router_providers.js:28 NavigationError {id: 2, url: "/my/workspace/1252407935628215305/projects", error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at match (http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9d…}error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at match (http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9dd9122cbbc98aa93a.js:74100:22)
    at matchPathsWithParamsAgainstRoute (http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9dd9122cbbc98aa93a.js:74073:19)
    at expandPathsWithParamsAgainstRoute (http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9dd9122cbbc98aa93a.js:74038:17)
    at expandPathsWithParams (http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9dd9122cbbc98aa93a.js:74020:21)
    at matchPathsWithParamsAgainstRoute (http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9dd9122cbbc98aa93a.js:74085:23)
    at expandPathsWithParamsAgainstRoute (http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9dd9122cbbc98aa93a.js:74038:17)
    at expandPathsWithParams (http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9dd9122cbbc98aa93a.js:74020:21)
    at expandSegment (http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9dd9122cbbc98aa93a.js:74010:17)
    at http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9dd9122cbbc98aa93a.js:74014:84
    at http://localhost:8080/vendor.6a9dd9122cbbc98aa93a.js:74367:41message: "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"stack: (...)get stack: stack()set stack: stack()__proto__: Errorid: 2url: "/my/workspace/1252407935628215305/projects"__proto__: Object
```

This is my router config setup:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  ...MyAppRoutes,
  { path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent}, 
  { path: 'signup', component: SignUpComponent},
  { path: 'join', component: JoinComponent},
  { path: 'version', component: VersionComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', terminal: true},
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes, {enableTracing: true})
];
```

MyAppRoutes:

```
export const MyAppRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: 'my',
    component: MyAppComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
      {path: 'profile', component: EditProfileComponent},
      {path: 'password', component: ChangePasswordComponent},
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', terminal: true},
      ...WorkspaceRoutes,
    ]
  },
];
```

WorkspaceRoutes

```
export const WorkspaceRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: 'workspace/:id', component: WorkspaceRootComponent},
  {children: [
    {path: 'projects', component: WorkspaceDashboardComponent},
    {path: 'newproject', component: ProjectNewComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', terminal: true},
  ]}
];
```

Routing works well at the top two levels (app routes and MyAppRoutes). But trying to navigate to any route such as `/my/workspace/1234/projects` fails with the above error. This same setup was working with the Angular2 beta and v2 routers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. In case anyone else hits a similar issue, the problem in this case was in WorkspaceRoutes.

```
export const WorkspaceRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: 'workspace/:id', component: WorkspaceRootComponent},
  {children: [    // this should not be the start of a new object
    {path: 'projects', component: WorkspaceDashboardComponent},
    {path: 'newproject', component: ProjectNewComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', terminal: true},
  ]}
];
```

Should be

```
export const WorkspaceRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: 'workspace/:id', 
  component: WorkspaceRootComponent,
  children: [
    {path: 'projects', component: WorkspaceDashboardComponent},
    {path: 'newproject', component: ProjectNewComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', terminal: true},
  ]}
];
```

The children item of WorkspaceRootComponent was not under that item, but on the same level.

Comment: Wow that is a subtle distinction and important difference! Thanks for posting. I was trying to figure this out for a long time. The error I was getting was: NavigationError : Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') at defaultUrlMatcher. Not helpful!